# Fetch API Delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, fetch

I'm attempting to fetch data on my server using the fetch API for the request, but the request is taking FOREVER to process (it does eventually process). I'm using React as my view, and Express is serving up my pages. I've listed my Express and JSX code below. Any insight into why this may be happening (The 'mounted' message is logged immediately as expected, but the fetch API after delays) ?

Express:

```
app.use('/test',function(){
          console.log('connected');
  })
```

React.JS:

```
componentDidMount(){
      console.log('mounted');
      fetch('./test').then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
      }).catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);
      })  
  }
```

Comment: Did you check the network request in the browsers developer tools? That will tell you whether the request is slow or you process the results in the wrong way.

Comment: You are not sending any response from your server so the browser waits and waits and waits and finally times out.  If you do `res.send("hello")` or some such response, the browser will get that very fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to send  the response in the server side :

```
app.use('/test',function(request, response){
          console.log('connected');
          response.send(); //!!!!! this line
         //Or:  response.sendStatus(200); to send status code without body

  });
```

... otherwise the endpoint will not be terminated.

Comment: Thanks for catching my error. It's always the trivial stuff that'll get you hung up.